# Show output values aka conversion-exit values in CDS?

Tags: abap, cds

I've created a CDS view, which reads some data from 2 tables.
My problem is, that one of the columns has a conversion policy behind - so if I display the data with `SE16n`, it shows the "converted value" but within my cds view only the unconverted value is shown.

Is there an option to show converted values in CDS views?

Comment: I guess you need to add ABAP logic to the CDS view. Did you try with a CDS Table Function?

Comment: I tried with Eclipse ADT --> create core data service. I guess there is no way to implement ABAP logic there

Comment: I was talking about Data Definition > next > next > select "Define Table Function with Parameters" but in fact it can be only HANA SQLscript, so forget it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use Virtual Elements

they can be used to calculate fields that are not available in CDS.

### Steps

1. Add a placeholder field: `cast( '' as abap.char(255)) AS after_conversion`
2. Add Annotation `@ObjectModel.virtualElement: true` to your field
3. Add Annotation `@ObjectModel.virtualElementCalculatedBy: 'ABAP:<z_class>'`
4. Create the Class `Z_CLASS`
5. Use interface `if_sadl_exit_calc_element_read`
6. In Method `calculate` you can do the conversion

[Here you can see a simple example](https://blogs.sap.com/2020/05/11/abap-code-exits-in-cds-views/)

Answer (score 3):

No actually conversion exits are not supported in CDS. But with string conversions you can rebuild the conversion exits.

-> see [Documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abencds_f1_sql_functions_character.htm)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).